# Moving mat-icon to left of expansion panel header title?

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, angular-material

I've changed the [Angular Material documentation expansion panel accordion demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jdmutr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexpansion-expand-collapse-all-example.html) slightly in order to move the account circle icon to the left of the title like this:

```
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-icon>account_circle</mat-icon>
      <mat-panel-title> Personal data </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
```

However it still appears on the right side.

How do we move the icon to the left of the title, while keeping the CSS within the declaring component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Change the order of the icon and the title using `order`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jdmutr-uqemru?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexpansion-expand-collapse-all-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Fexpansion-expand-collapse-all-example.css,src%2Fapp%2Fexpansion-expand-collapse-all-example.ts).

```
mat-panel-title {
  order: 1;
}

mat-icon {
  order: 0;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: I tried that and it puts the toggle icon (That comes with the panel) to the left ... However the account circle stays on the right ...

Comment: No. Account circle is on the left

Comment: parent i mean span with class `mat-content`.

Comment: Tried that as well ... It's still on the right ...

Comment: with `!important` ? For me it works.

Comment: Can you show a Stackblitz?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jdmutr-wsth5z?file=src%2Fstyles.scss

Comment: OH ... OK ... I see now.... I updated the css for the component with the rule and it did not take but it takes in styles.css ... Not sure I want to put it in there though ... because that will change the styles globally and I need to include the style with the component packaging that uses the expansion panel ...

Comment: Lukas I found a different solution and I updated the answer with it as it works with the components CSS file.  I upvoted and checked off the answer giving you credit.  Hope thats OK and thank you.

Comment: @Ole It is okay.